# Map/reduce java - code creating unknown output

Tags: java

The code ran fine, but the output was not as expected. My code is:

```
public class Test {

 public static class MapReduceMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(value.toString());
        String row;
        String[] pre;
        int[] tokens;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            row = scanner.nextLine();
            pre = row.split("\\t");
            tokens = new int[pre.length];

            for(int i=0; i<pre.length;i++) {
                tokens[i] = Integer.parseInt(pre[i]);
            }

                output.collect(new IntWritable(tokens[0]), new IntWritable(tokens[1]));

        }
    }
 } 

 public static class MapReduceReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, Text, NullWritable> {

 NullWritable NULL = NullWritable.get();

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, NullWritable> output) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            int a = val.get();
                count++;
        }

        String keyValue = key.get() + ": ";
        output.collect(new Text(keyValue + "Mean = " + (sum / count)), NULL);
        output.collect(new Text(keyValue + "Count = " + count), NULL);


    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    Job job = new Job(conf, "mapreduce");

    job.setJarByClass(test.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MapReduceMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MapReduceReducer.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("")); 
    String outputFile = "/home/kevmccar/mapreduce/output/";  
    Path outPath = new Path(outputFile);
    fs.delete(outPath, true);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputFile)); 

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

the input file I am using has a key and a value on each line such as:

```
1    1029109
5    289182
6    547849
1    389283
```

I want the output to be in the format of

```
1: Average = 12312
1: Count = 6564
```

but instead it looks like

```
5244    8       121602
5253    10      663603
5263    2       32288
5271    6       221095
5280    10      350834
5290    2       245710
5299    1       318947
5308    9       440945
5317    4       638909
...
```

Any reason why the output is what it is?

Comment: I think the `LongWritable key` in Map method is not what you're expecting it to be. the key being passed to the map method is the position of the line (value) in the file, the line being `1    1029109`, etc. You may want to use the `value` being passed to your mapper, which contains both the key & value pairs from your file

Comment: I changed the .toString in the mapper to line.toString which is what I had before. I ran with both and ended up with the same output.

Comment: where is your `line` defined?

Comment: wow, sorry I meant to say value.toString instead of line.toString

Comment: Ok, I went through your code in more detail, and I can't pinpoint where the error lies. However I suggest you look into this in more detail: `job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);` As far as my understanding goes, `setOutputKeyClass() and setOutputValueClass` should be used when your map & reduce emit the same type of keys & values. Since in your case, you're emitting different types of keys & values in your Map & Reduce, you might be better off using methods like `setMapOutputKeyClass` & `setMapOutputValueClass`, similarly for the reducer too.

Comment: Also try to print out some records from Map & Reduce methods and check those on the jobtracker logs to make sure that there's nothing wrong with your processing logic. Then we can narrow down the potential areas of error

Comment: read the edit for more info

Comment: `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);` This is wrong. It should be `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);`

Comment: but isnt the output for the map IntWritable?

Comment: oops, you're right. Sorry! Let me get back to you in a bit

Comment: I'm running the code on my system, I'll try & figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: input file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/228bplztb5jtgp7/input.txt.txt

Comment: Ok, so I think I generated the output you're looking for, although I'm not in a position to explain why you're current code isn't working. All I did was to convert the `OutputCollector` to `Context`. Honestly, I just did this because I'm not very familiar with `OutputCollector`. However, the code worked for me. So I'm pretty sure it has something to do with declaring types of key/values while using `OutputCollector`, so I suggest you look into that. I will post the code I have as an answer so that you can compare what I have modified(I also modified the input/output paths to be arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `OutputCollector` to `Context`, just because I'm more familiar with `Context` and I wasn't very sure how `OutputCollector` works. However, that change seemed to do the trick, so I'm assuming there was something wrong with the way key&value datatypes were declared using OutputCollector. Here is my code for reference:

```
public class HelloWorld {

   public static class MapReduceMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {


     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(value.toString());
        String row;
        String[] pre;
        int[] tokens;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
          row = scanner.nextLine();
          pre = row.split("\\t");
          tokens = new int[pre.length];

          for(int i=0; i<pre.length;i++) {
            tokens[i] = Integer.parseInt(pre[i]);
          }
          System.err.println("MapKey: " + tokens[0] + "MapValue: " + tokens[1]);
          context.write(new IntWritable(tokens[0]), new IntWritable(tokens[1]));

        }
        scanner.close();
     }
  } 

 public static class MapReduceReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, Text, NullWritable> {

   NullWritable NULL = NullWritable.get();

   public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (IntWritable val : values) {
        int a = val.get();
            if (a > max) {
                max = a; }
            else if (a < min) {
                a = min;
                        }
            sum += a;
            count++;
    }

    String keyValue = "Product "  + key.get() + ": ";
    context.write(new Text(keyValue + "Mean = " + (sum / count)), NULL);
    context.write(new Text(keyValue + "Count = " + count), NULL);
    context.write(new Text(keyValue + "Min = " + min), NULL);
    context.write(new Text(keyValue + "Max = " + max), NULL);

   }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   Configuration conf = new Configuration();
   FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

   Job job = new Job(conf, "mapreduce");

   job.setJarByClass(HelloWorld.class);

   job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
   job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
   job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
   job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

   job.setMapperClass(MapReduceMapper.class);
   job.setReducerClass(MapReduceReducer.class);

   job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
   job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

   FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0])); 
   String outputFile = args[1];  
   Path outPath = new Path(outputFile);
   fs.delete(outPath, true);
   FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputFile)); 

   job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

Sample Input:

```
1   1029109
5   289182
6   547849
```

Sample Output:

```
Product 5: Mean = 289182
Product 5: Count = 1
Product 5: Min = 2147483647
Product 5: Max = 289182
```

Comment: Yeah that seemed to do the trick. Thank's a lot for your time.